# Additional steps to oc new-app. Create autoscale policy

Tags: openshift

With oc new-app command (source strategy) several objects are created but not an horizontal pod autoscaler object.

Can it be automated that after the new-app command an horizontal pod autoscaler is created? Or should I do it manually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Template`[0] or custom script[1] to automate the process, because autoscaler is required deployment controller which is configured resources section to calculate the resource usage from autoscaler.

[0][Templates](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/templates.html)

[1] For example,

```
#!/bin/bash

oc new-app httpd &&
oc set resources dc/httpd --requests=cpu=100m &&
oc autoscale dc/httpd --min 1 --max 10 --cpu-percent=80

exit $?
```